# How to take a break during a CSS animation to pause at the center point of the transition?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I made a sort of header with an animated information banner (on 3 lines)
starting at each end. (ex: for the 1st and 3rd line, from left to right and for the 2nd line from right to left). What I would like is to take a break of a few seconds when the 3 bands are
all aligned (in the center) then continue the animation.

I would prefer a solution without using javascript but unfortunately I think it seems impossible?

**Problem**: The 1st and 3rd banner always start to appear before the 2nd and therefore when they are aligned, they are never in the center.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
 <head>
  <title> VIDEO LIBRARY </title>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   
      
        <style type="text/css">

.bandeau
{
    height: 120px;
    width:  100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background:  rgb(26,133,230);
   
}


@keyframes defilement {
 from {
    left: 0;
 }
 to {
    left: 1000px;
 }

}

 
.defil {
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.defil div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
}

.ex1 div {
    
    animation: defilement 20s linear infinite;
}

.ex2 div {
     top:0;
     right:0;
     
     background-color: white;
  
    animation: defilement 20s linear infinite reverse;
}

.ex3 div {
     
     background-color: red;
    
    animation: defilement 20s linear infinite ;
}



</style>
 
</head>


 <body>

           
            <div class="bandeau" >  
            
                <div class="defil ex1">
       
                    <div>MANAGEMENT</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="defil ex2">
        
                    <div>OF MY</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="defil ex3">
        
                    <div>VIDEO LIBRARY</div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
                
  
  
 
 
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `from` and `to` in your keyframes, you can set steps using percentages.

In the code below, from 0% to 45% of animation, the animation moves from 0 to 500px. Then from 45 - 55% it stays at 500px (i.e. pauses). Then from 55 - 100% it moves from 500 - 1000px:

```
@keyframes defilement {
    0% {left: 0;}
    45% {left: 500px;}
    55% {left: 500px;}
    100% {left: 1000px;}
}
```

**Responsive solution: blocks will stop in the centre an any size screen.**

If you do not have fixed width and would like a more responsive way to calculate the midpoint, you can use percentages: Start at 0%, end at 100%, then 50% for the centre.

However if you position the left of the block at the very centre, it will be a bit too far right. The correct position for the left of the block is actually `50% - 125px (half of the width of the div)`. And we can actually use using the CSS [`calc` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to do this!

Also to make all blocks appear at the same time, we need to change the starting point for `-250px` so the 3 blocks all start off the screen and then slide in together.

```
@keyframes defilement {
    0%   { left: -250px;}
    45%  { left: calc(50% - 125px); }
    55%  { left: calc(50% - 125px); }
    100% { left: 100%;}
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
.bandeau {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgb(26, 133, 230);
}

@keyframes defilement {
    0%   { left: -250px; }
    45%  { left: calc(50% - 125px); }
    55%  { left: calc(50% - 125px); }
    100% { left: 100%; }
}

.defil {
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.defil div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;

  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ex1 div {
  animation: defilement 20s linear infinite;
}

.ex2 div {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  animation: defilement 20s linear infinite reverse;
}

.ex3 div {
  background-color: red;
  animation: defilement 20s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="bandeau">

  <div class="defil ex1">
    <div>MANAGEMENT</div>
  </div>

  <div class="defil ex2">
    <div>OF MY</div>
  </div>

  <div class="defil ex3">
    <div>VIDEO LIBRARY</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

For more information on keyframes, take a look at [Mozilla MDN Docs for CSS3 Keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: Thank you very much FluffyKitten it works very well !!! :-))
I just have a small problem as I specified, the 2 bands on the left appear before the one on the right and therefore, when the animation is paused, the bands are well aligned but not in the center.
Should we play on animation-delay?

Comment: @Jean I've updated my answer with a responsive solution - I thought when you had used 1000px in your example that it was for a fixed with. The new solution will calculate the correct position to pause at so that the blocked are in the centre on any screen size.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you FluffyKitten.
This is exactly what I wanted !!!
 and say that I have struggled for days (or weeks) with that !!!
THANKS AGAIN.
We can say that you have a good mastery of this techno: -o)

Comment: @Jean Glad to help :) You had a lot of the hard work done yourself already, it was just the keyframes you needed help with! If this answer worked for you, you could consider accepting it so that the question gets marked as solved on the site, and also so other users know it helped you so they might also find it useful. Plus you get a few rep points :)

Comment: @Jean FYI, I've made one more change - I've changed the `0%` keyframe so that all the blocks start off the screen and then slide in together. I had missed that requirement until I edited your question :)

Comment: Ah yes !!, it's really more and more beautiful ;-))